# IIS ARR remove http request header?

Tags: iis-arr

We have a vendor web service behind the iis arr setup, for some reason it won't work with relic http request headers, unfrotunate since we have no insight to the code, we are thinking if any way to remove the http request header from the iis arr, please help! thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I seem to have the same issue as you have.
After trying a couple of things in IIS and doing debugging in Fiddler (using it as a reverse proxy between IIS and the application), i ended up trying to use Fiddler to alter the headers sent to the application. Here is what you would use to do that : http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy and http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse.

Here is the code i have added to the `OnBeforeRequest` method

```
oSession.oRequest.headers.Remove("Authorization");
```

It did work for me and seems the best way go for now.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, it merely gives a workaround (that can't be used server-side) with a debug tool.